# Google Calendar Events identify conflicting events

Tags: google-calendar-api

My application is using google calendar to read events as reservations to a specific room.

A room have a specific google calendar assigned to it, and anybody in the group can add a schedule/event/reservation.

With this, anybody can add a schedule and there is no checking for conflicts, etc. There can be conflicting events.

Since my application is reading calendar events, I thought there is a difference between the valid (first) event VS the conflicting event. But upon checking both events, I cannot find any field that can be used as an indicator that the event have conflicts. There is no way that my app cant tell which event is valid and which is in-conflict.

I tried setting `Auto accept invitations that do not conflict` in the google calendar settings but this won't work as I still get conflicting events.

My app have scheduled tasks that run periodically and it reads the calendar events and updates my list of reservations. My application removes those events/reservations that falls within range and updates it with the calendar events. But this includes the conflicting events/schedule.

Any idea on how I can set google calendar to avoid conflicting events?

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this?

Comment: I added some codes to check for conflicting events, just a simple checking if the current reservation exists or overlaps with the list of valid/existing reservations. Iterating each existing reservation and checking current reservation if it overlaps with the existing list. For checking the overlap, I call something like `validReservation.overlaps(currentReservation)`. If current reservation overlaps any of the existing reservations then it has conflict in schedule.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update! Sounds like you could probably post an answer to your own question :) I ended up having a look at the `freebusy` API endpoint, but it didn't seem to do what I wanted. Then I realised that all I am doing is booking events by the day so all I needed to do instead was do a quick `get` to check to make sure the day is free.